# Getting 404 not found error when calling GET method from AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, http, servlets

I was following this tutorial http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/angularjs-interacting-with-java-servlet-using-json/ (you can download source from bottom of the page) in Creating Java Servlet for Json and AngularJS. To be able to run the project, I imported gson jar (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/). However, on click I am getting a 404 not found error from the server. Could someone please explain what is wrong?

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.getDataFromServer = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/javaAngularJS'
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.person = data;
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });

    };
};
```

Webpage:

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="MyController">
        <button data-ng-click="getDataFromServer()">Fetch data from server</button>
        <p>First Name : {{person.firstName}}</p>
        <p>Last Name : {{person.lastName}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.model.PersonData;

    public class AngularJsServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public AngularJsServlet() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            PersonData personData = new PersonData();
            personData.setFirstName("Mohaideen");
            personData.setLastName("Jamil");

            String json = new Gson().toJson(personData);
            response.setContentType("application/json");
            response.getWriter().write(json);
        }
```

Model:

```
public class PersonData {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    }
```

I tested if json object was created properly in Servlet - json works.

The server is Tomcat v. 8

Comment: Well, you have to define your `controller` this way: `app.controller('MyController', MyController);`.

Comment: The controller works. I have also changed it as you suggested but the error is still the same.

Comment: If it works you're using Angular < 1.3..

Comment: Thank you. I connected angular.js from hosted google libraries (ver. 1.5.7) and defined controller as you suggested, the error is still 404 not found.

Comment: Try to check URL of servlet to which it is sending request . 404 means resource not found it could be either due to wrong url or container can be down. Could you please post mapping of servlet also so that it can be good

Comment: Yep, I checked it, if I remove the response part from the servlet code, I am getting status code 200, so it seems like a problem is with json response.